# Excel Add-ins get automatically disabled upon excel closure

Tags: excel, vba

After a while of not opening Excel on a specific PC, I have noticed that ALL the add-ins are disabled (even Solver and Data Analysis Tool packs). What I have noticed is that I am able to re-enable them by first deactivating and then activating them as one would normally do. And they all work just fine as usual. Unfortunately, once I close Excel and open it again, all the add-ins are once again disabled, even though Add-In Management dialogue box shows them being activated (ticked boxes)... I have tried to find the same issue both here and by googling but has been unsuccessful so far... Perhaps my query is not accurate enough. I would greatly appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: It might be the local policies that are causing the issue. Have you tried contacting your Help Desk to ask them if you are allowed to have non-standard add-ins?

Comment: @Zac, thank you for your comment. Yes, I have, and they'll look into it as well. But what is most surprising is that even Data Analysis (which I believe we can label as 'standard Excel add-in') is also prone to this strange error.

Comment: Have you always had this issue or is this a recent occurrence? It still sounds like a policy issue

Comment: @Zar, this is the first time ever that I see this...

Comment: UPDATE: It seems my IT admin has resolved the problem somehow.Not sure whether I should post this as an answer, though, in order to close the question.